# Error 'The application “Messages” can’t be opened.' after clicking on notification.

Tags: notifications, messages, error

Messages is open and working, but not the active application. I get a text, the top right hand notification comes in. I want to go to the Messages app so I click the notification and get this error.

The application “Messages” can’t be opened.

[image]

But then I just click on Messages in the dock and it works fine?